# How to set axis size in GNU Octave?

Tags: plot, octave

I am plotting a 3d surf plot in Octave and I want the z axis to be between 0 and 10. Can you please tell to to set axis to be between 2 values. The function ranges between 0 and 8 in z axis, but I want the z axis to be from 0 to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `zlim` command.

```
zlim([0,10]);
```

Or, the axis command with 6 arguments, but in that case you'd have to specify limits for X and Y too.

Here's an example

```
t = 0 : 0.1 : pi * 12;
x = cos(t); y = sin(t); z = t / pi;
plot3( x, y, z );
zlim([0,20]);
```

Comment: Its is not working on my laptop, the z axis is still between 0 to 8 even after running this command.

Comment: @KalpeshBhatnagar sorry the syntax was wrong, it should be z([0,10]) not z(0,10). Having said that, if it's not working even with this syntax, you are probably calling zlim _before_ plotting. Any plot command resets the limits, so you'll have to apply this after you're done with plotting.